# How to wrap long code lines in google-code-prettify

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting

I'm using default setting of google-code-prettify. When a line is too long, it exceeds the boundary, like the following: [image] Are they any possible solution to wrap the code line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the CSS property `word-wrap: break-word;` to enable word-wrapping. Make sure that your selector has priority over Google's style, as they probably set `word-wrap: nowrap;` somewhere.

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work. Maybe it did in 2014 but now it doesn't

Comment: Does not work. @DustinPoissant's answer is the correct one with: `pre { white-space: pre-wrap; }`

Answer (score 15):

You need to use `pre-wrap`.

```css
pre {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Comment: Note you may need to use the CSS selector `.prettyprint {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}`

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is changing the `overflow` to `auto`

```
pre {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone using linenums you need this

```
:not(pre) > code {
    white-space: pre-wrap; 
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```